# Shift the ordinal index of a table column to the left

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following snippet of a table: 
[image]

There are 14 columns in this particular table and all of the columns not shown are OK, but starting with the `strength` column all of the values have been shifted over one ordinal position to the right.  So 100MG should be strength and not days_sup, quantity should go in the days_sup column, drug_class should be filled with the data that's currently in H4B.  At the end, everything before the comma in std_cost should go one column to the left and everything to the right of the column should stay in std_cost.  So a snippet of what they table should look like would be (shortened for brevity's sake): (SQL Server 2008)

```
strength   days_sup   drug_class   dispfee   std_cost
100MG      6          H4B          1.5       5.06
```

This error in the table only happens in about .05% of the entire table's rows, and happens with the condition 
`where std_cost like '%,%'.
Is there anyway I can update all of these columns at once?  I was thinking it might be possible using a sequence table and the ordinal index of the column.

Comment: Do you use the same query to extract your data columns or a different query for when you use the query std_cost like '%,%' ?

Comment: I use the same query just without the where clause filter.  Anything that's fine won't be affected in the update query as long as the where clause filter is in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've got it right - something like this:

```
update t 
SET strength=days_sup,
    days_sup=quantity,
    quantity=drug_class,
    drug_class=fst_fill,
    fst_fill=rfl_nbr,
    rfl_nbr=prc_typ,
    prc_typ=dispfee,
    dispfee=SUBSTRING(std_cost,1,CHARINDEX(',',std_cost,1)-1)
    std_cost=SUBSTRING(std_cost,CHARINDEX(',',std_cost,1)+1,100)

where std_cost like '%,%';
```

Comment: And to think, I was going to make this much harder on myself.  +1 for a nice, simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only have about 9 columns have problem, I would do it manually. Like this,

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET strength =  days_sup 
  , days_sup = quantity
  .....
  ,  dispfee  = LEFT( STD_COST, CHARINDEX(',',STD_COST) -1 )
  ,   STD_COST = RIGHT (STD_COST, LEN(STD_COST) - CHARINDEX(',',STD_COST))
where std_cost like '%,%'
```